# How to turn off openfire autostart on osx

Tags: macos, autostart

I run openfire for development every once in a while on my OSX Lion and want it to run only if i turn it on in the pref pane. Although I did not check the system start checkbox, it is always started after a reboot. I tried any combination of turning it on and then reboot, turning it off and reboot, set the check, unset the check. It's always running on a rebooted system. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jivesoftware.openfire.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Try unloading the launchd plist:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jivesoftware.openfire.plist
```

Comment: mcnesium@mcobst:~$ sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jivesoftware.openfire.plist
launchctl: Error unloading: org.jivesoftware.openfire :(